# Import products with complex categories structure from excel file

Tags: django, excel, import, satchmo

I want to synchronize satchmo store with 1c.
In other words, I need to import categories (with hierarchical system), products, product's images. And export orders to .xls, (excel file).

Do you know any ready to use solutions?

P.S. I found http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2255/ and http://code.google.com/p/django-satchmo-tuning/
Do you know better aproach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use cool app from **satels**: http://satels.blogspot.com/2011/12/django-import-excel.html